# Нужно записать в переменную несколько значений

Tags: lua

В моей игре есть около 50 предметов, каждому из них присвоена отдельная цифра.

Мне нужен способ, который позволит записать в одну переменную много числовых значений, для вызова предмета по цифре, которую ввел игрок.

Если я захватываю весь скрипт циклом `for example = 0,50 do`, все работает, но в игре появляется нежелательный лаг из-за повторения большого скрипта.

Если я записываю значения от 0 до 50 в функцию и возвращаю ее return-ом, то при обращении к функции ничего не происходит, вероятно я делаю что-то не так.

Comment: А вы покажите, как вы делаете, чтобы можно было понять что не так?

Comment: Не знаком с Lua, но что мешает держать элементы в массиве?

Comment: Записать несколько значений в переменную априори невозможно, если только это не таблица. Просто используйте таблицу. И да, мне самому это не нравится, но в `lua` счет начинается с 1

Comment: И ноль это труЪ :)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch непривычно

Comment: @AlexeyTen необычно 0_о

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch спасибо вам большое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример использования таблицы в качестве массива:

```
local items = {1, 2, 3, "hello", 5.6}

for i, v in ipairs(items) do
  print(i .. ": " .. v)
end
```

напечатает:

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: hello
5: 5.6
```

---

Обращение по индексу (нумерация начинается с 1):

```
print(items[1])
print(items[4])
print(items[5])
```

напечатает:

```
1
hello
5.6
```